# MongoDB - Updating the field type of all objects within an array from String to Int32/64

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm fairly new to mongodb so please bear with me.

As per title, what I want to achieve is to convert a specific field in all documents within an array of a document from String to Int how do i do that?

**Sample Doc :**

```
{
 reviews:[
    {
      snid:"1242"
    },
    {
      snid:"8392"
    }
 ]
}
```

And my objective is to convert all of the **snid**'s from **String** to **Int32**

so far i understand that we can use something like `db.collection.update()` but this will update a specific field, not an array.

Another attempt is

```
db.collection.find({},{reviews:1,_id:0},(err,doc)=>{
    //How do i push it back to the document
})
```

But as you can tell, I'm not entirely sure on how we should push the updated document back into the same array of sorts.

Any insights will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you whoami for helping edit my question ! Really appreciate it any help I can get :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If you're using MongoDB version >= `4.2`, try below query :

```
db.collection.update({'reviews.snid' : {$exists : true}}, [
  {
    $set: {
      reviews: {
        $map: { input: "$reviews", in: { 'snid': { $toInt: "$$this.snid" } } }
      }
    }
  }
],{multi :true})
```

Above query uses [Aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#examples) in `.update()` which was introduced in version `4.2`, You can also use `.updateMany()` instead of `.update()`.

**It works on documents of below type :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e810f5ec16b5679b43a2f0e"),
    "reviews" : [ 
        {
            "snid" : '1242'
        }, 
        {
            "snid" : '8392'
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e810f6ac16b5679b43a310c"),
    "reviews" : [ 
        {
            "snid" : '1242232'
        }, 
        {
            "snid" : '8391232'
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8110b1c16b5679b43a5148"),
    "abc" : 1
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e8110c3c16b5679b43a52f9"),
    "reviews" : []
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e811359c16b5679b43a9229"),
    "reviews" : [ 
        {
            "abc" : "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

**But above update query will partially work if you've a doc like below :**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e811359c16b5679b43a9230"),
    "reviews" : [ 
        {
            "abc" : "1"
        },
        {
            "snid" : "123"
        }
    ]
}
```

In that case you need to use [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html) to do a conditional check in `$map` to see if current object has key **snid** then convert value or else pass on the same object as is to 'reviews' array.

2) Just in Case if your MongoDB version is < `4.2`/`4.0` & > `3.2` - You can use [.bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html) :

Cause you can not use **Aggregation Pipeline** in update & also [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/index.html). So you need to do `.find()` to get entire docs & write code to convert these from strings to integers & use `.bulkWrite()` to update docs in one update DB call (You can take `_id` as key for each document).

3) You can also write an [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) query on existing collection & use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) to update entire collection or write aggregation result to new collection by running just one query. I would prefer to temporarily write it to new collection to check data is correct & rename new collection to what ever is existing by naming existing with something ends with `_backup` used as backup.

Comment: Thank you whoami ! This gives me lots of material to work with... Seems like I still have lots to learn from mongodb!